# How to remove text selection that is highlighted when we copy to clipboard using javascript

Tags: javascript, copy, clipboard, paste

I am using the below code to copy and paste the text to clipboard using javascript. It basically selects the HTML element and shows a highlighter on that particular element . Is it possible to remove the highlighter or any other way to handle this scenario?

```
 copyInputMessage(inputElement){
    inputElement.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    inputElement.setSelectionRange(0, 0);
  }
```

Comment: *shows a highlighter on that particular element*. What highlighter?

Comment: For example, https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_copy_clipboard , when i click on Copy text , it highlights the Hello world text with blue color, I dont want this to happen, because in my case, i am using a hidden text area element . The text from this hidden needs to be copied to clipboard. In this case, it highlights the hidden element with blue color which is not present on screen .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
copyInputMessage(inputElement){
    inputElement.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    inputElement.setSelectionRange(0, 0);
    inputElement.blur(); 
}
```